# How to create a new InfoPath form in form library programatically using an event handler?

Tags: development, sharepoint-server, infopath, form-library

I would like to add Infopath form, that is a new item in the Form library programmatically. This would be using any event handler.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

See this link, which solves the same problem:

https://xodeuz.wordpress.com/2015/06/15/programmatically-create-new-item-in-form-library/

I copy here the text from the article in case it goes down in the future:

> InfoPath item creation has always been a bit tricky since there is a
>   dependency with the template.xml inside the MyForm.xsn.
>
> What we essentially did was automatically extract this template file
>   from the published .xsn form. Allowing the form to be updated without
>   causing issues to with code.
>
> There is a great CabExtractor that i found on CodeProjects and
>   Stackoverflow:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533105/minimum-c-sharp-code-to-extract-from-cab-archives-or-infopath-xsn-files-in-mem
>
> This CabExtractor allows us to open up the published xsn file and
>   extract the template.xml from the compressed file.

```
public static void ExtractTemplateFile(string xsnPath) {
    byte[] data = null;
    var fileStream = SPContext.Current.Web.GetFile(xsnPath).OpenBinaryStream();
    try {
        data = new byte[fileStream.Length];
        fileStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    } finally {
        fileStream.Dispose();
    }
    byte[] buffer;
    int bufferLength;
    using(CabExtract extractor = new CabExtract(data)) {
        extractor.ExtractFile("template.xml", out buffer, out bufferLength);
    }
    using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
        string content = "";
        using(MemoryStream templateStream = new MemoryStream(buffer)) {
            using(StreamReader reading = new StreamReader(templateStream)) {
                content = reading.ReadToEnd();
                content = content.Replace("solutionVersion = \", "href = \"" + SPContext.CurrentWeb.Url + " / MyLibrary / Forms / template.xsn\"solutionVersion = \"");
            }
        }
        using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(ms)) {
            writer.Write(content);
            writer.Flush();
        }
        SPFile templateFile = SPContext.Current.Web.Files.Add(" / SiteAssets / template.xml", ms.ToArray());
        templateFile.Update();
    }
}
```

> Once we’ve extracted the file we can now create a new file in the form
>   library using the data from the template.xml and then populating the
>   promoted properties on that content type.

```
public static void CreateNewFormItem(MyDTO data) {
    SPList list = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists.TryGetList("MyLibrary");
    SPFile template = SPContext.Current.Web.GetFile(" / SiteAssets / template.xml");
    byte[] fileData = template.OpenBinary();
    SPFile newFile = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(list.RootFolder.Url + " / " + data.Title + ".xml", fileData);
    newFile.Update();
    // Populate item with data from DTO
    SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(file.Item.ID);
    item["Somefield"] = data.SomeField;
    item.Update();
}
```

> Something to take note on while updating the SPListItem object from
>   the form library is that some fields might be set to ReadOnly. One way
>   to handle this to set the fields that you will need to populate to not
>   be read only in code for example in a Feature. Or a class that
>   temporarily set the fields to be editable and the switch them back to
>   read only mode once the item has been updated.